# Pick a value from different columns based on the condition

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have this situation: 3 columns contains DATES, and based on the value of other 2 columns, I have to pick up one or another. Before, I`ve done it through excel with this function: `=arrayformula(if((S2:S="")*(AA2:AA="")=1,Y2:Y,if((REGEXMATCH(B2:B,"2-Learn")=TRUE)*(REGEXMATCH(C2:C,"B2BSales")=TRUE)=1,AA2:AA,if(S2:S="",AA2:AA,S2:S))))`

in words: if 'Minimum' and 'Due Date' are empty, pick the value from 'DATE'
if BUF = 2-Learn AND Function = B2BSales, pick 'Due Date'
if 'Minimum' is empty, pick Due Date
Otherwise, pick 'Minimum'

The DB is called Records, table is transactions

```
BUF      Function    Minimum      Date      DueDate      Results
a           e        01/02/22   02/05/22    01/05/22    01/02/22
b           d        -          05/05/22     -          05/05/22 
c         B2BSales   -          05/03/22    01/05/22    01/05/22
b2        B2BSales   02/05/22   05/01/22    03/05/22    02/05/22
2-Learn   B2BSales   02/05/22   05/01/22    03/05/22    03/05/22
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this through a CASE statement in your SELECT.

```
SELECT
[BUF] = Records.BUF,
[Function] = Records.Function,
[Date] = CASE WHEN (Records.Minimum IS NULL AND Records.DueDate IS NULL) THEN Records.Date
WHEN Records.BUF = '2-Learn' AND Records.Function = 'B2BSales' THEN Records.DueDate
WHEN Records.Minimum IS NULL THEN REcords.DueDate
ELSE Records.Minimum
END

FROM ....
```